# summarise_each works but summarise_all doesn't

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the summarise_all function in dplyr.

When I use the deprecated version, "summarise_each" it works fine but when I do summarise_all, I get an error.

Dataset:

```
Date <- as.Date(c('2017-10-16',
              '2017-10-16',
              '2017-10-17',
              '2017-10-17',
              '2017-10-18',
              '2017-10-18',
              '2017-10-19',
              '2017-10-19',
              '2017-10-20',
              '2017-10-20'))

Source <- as.Date(c('2017-11-29',
                '2017-11-30',
                '2017-11-29',
                '2017-11-30',
                '2017-11-29',
                '2017-11-30',
                '2017-11-29',
                '2017-11-30',
                '2017-11-29',
                '2017-11-30'))

Column1 <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")

Column2 <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")


Revenue <- c(206.88,
         210.88,
         194.13,
         200.13,
         170.00,
         170.00,
         746.65,
         736.65,
         772.00,
         772.00)

Cost <- c(100.88,
      10.88,
      85.13,
      100.13,
      170.00,
      100.00,
      46.65,
      50.65,
      23.00,
      24.00)

df <- data.frame(Date, Source, Column1, Column2, Revenue, Cost)
```

Dataframe:

```
df

             Date     Source Column1 Column2 Revenue   Cost
    1  2017-10-16 2017-11-29       A       A  206.88 100.88
    2  2017-10-16 2017-11-30       A       A  210.88  10.88
    3  2017-10-17 2017-11-29       A       A  194.13  85.13
    4  2017-10-17 2017-11-30       A       A  200.13 100.13
    5  2017-10-18 2017-11-29       A       A  170.00 170.00
    6  2017-10-18 2017-11-30       B       B  170.00 100.00
    7  2017-10-19 2017-11-29       B       B  746.65  46.65
    8  2017-10-19 2017-11-30       B       B  736.65  50.65
    9  2017-10-20 2017-11-29       B       B  772.00  23.00
    10 2017-10-20 2017-11-30       B       B  772.00  24.00
```

This is the code for `summarise_each`:

```
by_date_test<-df %>%
group_by(Date) %>%
summarise_each(funs(sum), -c(`Column1`, 
                             `Column2`))
```

I get a new dataframe but a warning comes up saying:

```
`summarise_each()` is deprecated.
Use `summarise_all()`, `summarise_at()` or `summarise_if()` instead.
To map `funs` over a selection of variables, use `summarise_at()`
```

When I try it with `summarise_all` this is the error I get:

```
 by_date_test<-df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum), -c(`Column1`, 
                              `Column2`))

Error in -c(Column1, Column2) : invalid argument to unary operator
```

What am I doing wrong with summarise_all? Also my actual dataset has about 1000 columns and I want to exclude selected columns.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Changed it to have a reproducible example

Comment: You don't actually want to summarise *all* the columns, so `summarise_all` is a bad choice. Seems like you want to summarise  all but Column1 or Column2, a "selection of variables", so try `summarise_at`.

Comment: I have about 1000 columns and I want to summarise all but the selected. Would summarise_at still work?

Comment: Yes, it will...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y_date_test<-df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-Column1, -Column2), sum)
```

Demo:

```
group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-mpg, -wt), mean)
# # A tibble: 3 x 9
#     cyl     disp        hp     drat     qsec        vs        am     gear     carb
#   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     4 105.1364  82.63636 4.070909 19.13727 0.9090909 0.7272727 4.090909 1.545455
# 2     6 183.3143 122.28571 3.585714 17.97714 0.5714286 0.4285714 3.857143 3.428571
# 3     8 353.1000 209.21429 3.229286 16.77214 0.0000000 0.1428571 3.285714 3.500000
```